# How to pass an array of complex objects to an IEnumerable parameter in the URI

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am able to pass arrays of simple types in the URI (i.e. GET requests). I am also able to pass complex objects in the URI.

However, I have not been able to pass an array of complex objects.

If I have a class, say,

```
class Person {
  public FirstName { get; set;}
  public LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And my Web API action method's parameter is an `IEnumerable<Person>`, how should the URI look like? If it helps, I am using JavaScript to make the GET request.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to include your controller method.  But from what you are describing a little bit of code for a model binder would make it fairly easy for you to pass a list of people in any format you want in either the querystring or as part of the posted body content.

Here's a link to asp.net core model binding that is current at the time of this writing.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1  It'll probably stop working someday but you can always use your favorite search engine to look for `model binder` and get current info.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your collection of objects using JSON.

```
var lstPersons = [
{  FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe" },
{  FirstName: "Bob", LastName: "Sams" },
{  FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Doe" }
];

$.ajax({
    url: "/api/person",
    data: JSON.stringify({ pos: lstPersons }) ,
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8'
    type: 'POST',
});
```

To deserialize your JSON object in your web api you can use the documentation below for guidance.

[Deserialize with CustomCreationConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your help; however my question was specifically about using a GET post and passing the array of complex objects in the URL.